# Post javascript variables to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am  trying to post variables from a js function into my database, I've tried several things but it wont pass it to php. How can I solve this? I've added the code i'm working with.

Any help will be highly appreciated

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<?php
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root','', 'koopwoningen');
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT Adres FROM geocodetest");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$data = array();
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $data[] = $row["Adres"];

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var adresses = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

for(i=0;i<adresses.length;i++){
var address = adresses[i];

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "geocode.php?latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude);
                    xmlhttp.send();

    alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);

    } 

}); 
}



</script>
<?php

$lati = isset($_POST['latitude']);
$lngi = isset($_POST['longitude']);

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO geocodetest (lat, lng) VALUES ($lati, $lngi)") or die(mysql_error());  
?>
</html>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client–server_model : PHP happens on server before anything is rendered on the client, including JS.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` returns a string containing the JSON. Therefore you need to add single quotes. Change this:

```
var adresses = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
```

To this:

```
var adresses = '<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>';
```